# UDID iphone in http header request

Tags: iphone, http, header

it's possible to let my iPhone send automatically the UDID in all http request header?

Comment: No, also the UDID is deprecated and will be romoved by Apple.

Comment: thx for the response.
My problem is:
that i want to differentiate between iphones hoes are passed from my proxy over 3G.
have you any idea??

Comment: I thought about ip adresse but in 3G all the devices are sharing the same public ip adress

Comment: @rckoenes it will be replaced by other methods in ios6, so deprecation should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own UUID that you can add to your header if you want. Save the UUID in preferences.

Maybe do this in `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"deviceID"]) {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:uuidString forKey:@"deviceID"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    CFRelease(uuid);
}
```

You can then add the header to a `NSMutableURLRequest`

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"deviceID"]
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Device-ID"];
```

Comment: THX But i want to send it automatically in all http request launched by the iphone not only in the request started by my app.

Comment: That is not possible without jailbreaking.